# Very slow wifi connection on 14.04

Tags: 14.04, wireless, internet

I have a Toshiba Satellite running Ubuntu 14.04. My partner has a Toshiba Satellite running Windows 7, both using the same TP-Link WiFi modem. He gets
around 8-9 Mbps while I get between 1.44 - 2.0 Mbps (our rural area is still in the dark ages). I have just spent an hour on the phone to the ISP technician,done multiple speedtests, both with WiFi and with cable. Either way I lose out each time. Is something internal blocking my bandwidth? I only recently reinstalled 14.04 after a 16.04 install failed, so its all still 'uncontaminated'. The internet speed hasn't changed from before the install to now. Really hope someone has a solution for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting a driver parameter

```
sudo -i
echo "options rtl8188ee msi=1"  >  /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8188ee.conf
exit
```

Reboot and check

Comment: Did that. Speedtest now reads between 0.31 and 0.87 Mbps. So the condition is now worse!!?

Comment: Try to change the DNS addresses as well

Comment: Hmmm, trying to check that one out. I'm uncertain how to proceed.

Comment: follow thishttps://www.opennicproject.org/configure-your-dns/how-to-set-up-dns-servers-in-ubuntu-linux/

Comment: follow the link     https://www.opennicproject.org/configure-your-dns/how-to-set-up-dns-servers-in-ubuntu-linux/

Comment: Did that. Speedtest download rate is still around 0.65 Mbps?!!

Comment: How would I restore the previous driver parameter?

Comment: remove this content from file          "options rtl8188ee msi=1"

Answer (score 0):

One way that speeds up wifi (worked for me) is using another network manager.
The Ubuntu Network Manager is not really the best and may cause problems with connection speeds.

I will suggest switching to a different network manager.
My recommended network manager is [Wicd](http://wicd.sourceforge.net/download.php)

Wicd is fast and reliable if you set it up correctly. Google is your help for installing Wicd properly